# Neo4j updated when I didn't intend it to

Tags: neo4j, upgrade, updates

I had a local instance of Neo4j at version 3.3.1. This morning my Ubuntu Software updater listed a number of updates that were available amongst which was "Grah database engine" or similar.  I selected to install the updates without giving enough thought to it and it now seems to have installed Neo4j version 3.4.7.

Clearly I'm aware that it's a good idea to upgrade, but this wasn't planned and I haven't followed the upgrade planning steps outlined here: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/upgrade/planning/

Further the version I have locally now doesn't match the live applications I have running on web servers.

I don't have time or resources to do full planned upgrades this week, but do need to access and use the database.

What is my best course of action please?  Should I try and downgrade the database engine to 3.3.1 again?  How would I do that?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I think I've sorted this.  This approach worked fine because I have my database file locations **OUTSIDE** the normal Neo4j installation.  You wouldn't want to do this if you store your data in the default /var/lib/neo4j/data location as I believe `apt-get purge` would delete your data.

In case it's helpful for others.

First I backed up /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf.

Then uninstalled Neo4j 3.4.7:

`sudo apt-get purge neo4j*`

Then I re-installed with version 3.3.1:

`sudo apt-get install neo4j=3.3.1`

I restored the database location paths `dbms.directories.data` in /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf.

Started Neo4j.

All seems good.